# Persistent-mysql crashes on database migration on Fedora 27

Tags: haskell, yesod

I am trying to move build my yesod application on a new development machine. Although the build proceeds without error when I try to run the application using either $ stack exec -- yesod devel or $ stack exec app I get the messages:

> Starting devel application
>   Unexpected: child process exited with ExitFailure (-11)
>   Trying again

and on in an endless loop until I interrupt.

Looking at the mysql query log suggests that the application is going directly to querying the database with no migration step and the mariadb.log reports "[Warning] Aborted connection" and "(Got an error reading communication packets)"

The problem is reproducible for me with a new yesod-mysql scaffold site:

```
$ stack new testDB yesod-mysql
$ stack install yesod-bin --install-ghc
$ stack build
```

then in mysql:

```
> create database testDB;
> grant all privileges on testDB.* to 'testDB'@'localhost' identified by 'testDB';
```

and finally:

```
$ stack exec -- yesod devel
```

Any pointers to where I may be going wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: I've hit this problem too on Fedora 28 - did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: I have raised Issue [#1531](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/issues/1531) in the Yesod GitHub about this.

Comment: Could you say what version of Yesod that you were using?

Comment: I tried updating Yesod versions and still encountered the problem up to 1.4.5 and I've not managed to solve it myself yet.

Comment: I've recently found a work-round for this by switching from persistent-mysql to persistent-mysql-haskell which removes the underlying dependancy on the mysql library where I suspect the issue lies.  There are helpful notes on the swap in the yesod context see: <https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-mysql-haskell>.